# ServerSocket - how to keep client socket id

Tags: java, sockets, inheritance

I tried to extend Socket object something as...

```
public class TestSocket extends Socket
{
  private String id=String.valueOf(Math.random());

  ...

  public void setId(String id){this.id=id;}
  public String getId(){return this.id;}

}
```

init as...

```
TestSocket testSocket = new TestSocket(SERVER_HOSTNAME, SERVER_PORT);
```

As I can see it, the server side ServerSocket standard code like a

```
TestSocket mySocket = (TestSocket) serverSocket.accept();
```

... according to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) accept() method re-inits socket object and returns a new one so the id value is not the client's one but a regenerated one :(

Is it possible to keep a client id? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the line

```
TestSocket mySocket = (TestSocket) serverSocket.accept();
```

would raise a `ClassCastException` since `java.io.ServerSocket.accept()` returns an instance of class `Socket`, not `TestSocket` (unless you inherited from ServerSocket).

You probably have to send the ID over the connection and set it on the receiving end if you want to connect the two sockets, like:

```
public void sendID() {
   DataOutputStreak dos = new DataOutputStream(getOuputStream());
   dos.writeUTF(this.getId());
}

public void receiveID() {
   DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(getInputStream());
   setId(dis.readUTF());
}
```

One of your two test sockets would call the one method and the other the other.
I would not, however, inherit from the Socket classes to perform this, but handle this on a higher level.

Comment: it's OK I extended ServerSocket too so no ClassCastException is expected.

Comment: ... but the accept() method is a real badluck. Send ID via connection? What you mean?

Comment: @user592704: I have justed edited my post according to your comment.

Comment: I guess it is an interesting way :) But is it possible to avoid the post identification?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to keep your sockets in a data structure, ie. a Map.

Comment: You could implement it however you wanted. Why do you want to give a client connection a unique id?

Comment: Could you give a good snippet example the the "Map" using way?

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by `getRemoteSocketAddress()` of the accepted socket is unique (because clients will either have different IP addresses or different ports within the same IP address). That's all you need.